# Can I play Minecraft only using the Wii U gamepad?

Tags: wii-u, minecraft-legacy-console

I'm trying to decide if I should get Minecraft for the PS4 or Wii U. My kids will be the ones playing it. I'd like them to be able to play with just the Wii U's gamepad while I do something else on the TV. **Can you play Minecraft only with the Wii U's gamepad?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Yes.

From the wiki article on the [Wii-U-Edition](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Wii_U_Edition):

> The Wii U Edition features Off-TV Play, allowing the game to be played only on the GamePad.